# Why does this piece of code loop infinitely?

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I am in the process of writing a search engine for the experience and the knowledge. Right now, I am in the process of building a crawler and its accompanying utilities. One of these is the URL normalizer. This is what I am trying to build right now, and more specifically I am stuck at the point where I have to make a method to take a url, and capitalize letters that follow a '%' sign. My code so far:

```
def escape_sequence_capitalization(url):
        ''' The method that capitalizes letters in escape sequences.
        All letters within a percent - encoding triplet (e.g. '%2C') are case
        insensitive and should be capitalized.

        '''
    next_encounter = None
    url_list = []
    while True:
        next_encounter = url.find('%')
        if next_encounter == -1:
            break

        for letter in url[:next_encounter]:
            url_list.append(letter)

        new_character = url[next_encounter + 1].upper()
        url_list.append(new_character)
        url = url[next_encounter:]

    for letter in url:
        url_list.append(letter)

    return ''.join(url_list)
```

Can someone please guide me to where my error is? I would be grateful. Thank you.

EDIT: this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
http://www.example.com/a%c2%b1b → http://www.example.com/a%C2%B1b
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By static analysis, it loops forever because your `while True` never breaks. So where can it break? Only at the `break` statement only if the `next_encounter` becomes equal to -1; so you can deduce that it never does.

Why doesn't it? Try a `print next_encounter` after `url.find`. You'll quickly see that

```
url = url[next_encounter:]
```

does almost what you hope it will, only it gives you one character more than you hoped.

Why did I present it this way? Mostly because the value of `print` is often underrated by people learning the language.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was most insightful. I do not underestimate the value of print(), really, print methods and functions is the main debugging tool I use in other programming languages, it's just that it didn't strike me due to my lack of experience. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

@msw nailed it and gave sound advice.

My $.02 is you never should have tried this loop

How about:

```
>>> re.sub('%..',lambda m: m.group(0).upper(),'http://www.example.com/a%c2%b1b')
'http://www.example.com/a%C2%B1b'
```

Comment: Sounds like a plan, however I am a Python newbie, and lambdas are kinda confusing for me at the moment, so if I could avoid them, I would prefer to do so.

Comment: lambda is nothing but a one line function. could have created a function like in the [docs for `re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).   Embrace the functional paradigm. Resistance is futile.

Comment: Lol'd at the 'Embrace the functional paradigm. Resistance is futile.' part. Nice one mate.

Comment: @NlightNfotis: If lambdas confuse you, you should use them more, not avoid them. Avoiding concepts that you don't understand isn't going to help you in the long run.

Comment: @JoelCornett You speak the truth brother, however, I would like to be a little bit more comfortable with the python language before I get to use them.

Answer (score 3):

This is why:

```
>>> 'asd'.find('s')
1
>>> 'asd'[1:]
'sd'
```

Also, consider using the second argument to `str.find()` instead of slicing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm coming a bit late to the party, but you might want to consider using a regular expression instead of such a complicated function:

```
>>> import re
>>> url = "http://www.example.com/a%c2%b1b"
>>> result = re.sub("(?i)%[0-9A-F]{2}", lambda x: x.group(0).upper(), url)
>>> result
'http://www.example.com/a%C2%B1b'
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?i)          # Make regex case-insensitive
%             # Match a %
[0-9A-F]{2}   # Match two hex digits
```

`re.sub()` finds all these occurrences in the string and passes the result (the match object's `group(0)`) to the `.upper()` method, then replaces the original with the uppercased version of the match.

Comment: Great answer. Will consider your approach.